# Magento2 Production mode

Tags: magento2

Can anyone help me to for the below error while updating from **default mode to production mode** in **magento2** I get the below error .

> **Error:** Command returned non-zero exit code

Thanks in advance

Comment: increase the memory limit in `php.ini to 512M` and then check is it worked or not . To increased memory temporary you can use like `php -dmemory_limit=1G namespace:command`

Answer (score 2):

You need to increased Php memory from php.ini file .

You can increase the memory limit in **php.ini to 512M** and then check is it worked or not .

To increased memory temporary you can use like **php -dmemory_limit=1G namespace:command**

For more reference refer this link - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2972